# Infinite while not doing it's loop

Tags: python

I want it to loop it back to the Class of the value input is not in the option I am trying learning OOP Class encapsulation

I have already tried using "return" with the class name or functions inside the calls I am not getting any luck.

```
class Main:

    def main_page(main_1):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3'];
        choice = input()

        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            main_page()



        if choice == '1':
            print("Hello world")
        elif choice == '2':
            print("back world")


        else:
            quit()

mainout = Main()
mainout.main_page()
```

when I input number part from 1,2,3 i get this error

```
" Invalid Please try again                                                                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>                                                                                                                                             
    mainout.main_page()                                                                                                                                                            
  File "main.py", line 17, in main_page                                                                                                                                            
    main_page()                                                                                                                                                                    
NameError: name 'main_page' is not defined                                                                                                                                                                                      "
```

Comment: are you intending to write a recursive function?

Comment: *edited 

Hello vurmux yes maybe we can put it that way. My goal is when I press numbers that are not '1', '2' , '3' it should go back to the part  it ask you to choose from 1 to 3

Comment: 1) `main_page()` takes an input parameter that you do not provide.  2) Where did `quit()` come from?

Comment: `main_page` is method in class so you have to use `self.main_page()`  inside `main_page()` to run it again. But it makes recursion which is not prefered method.

Answer (score 3):

1. Every method in class (except static/class, which are special) must contain the first argument - `self`. So in your case you should write:

`def main_page(self, main_1):`

2. You don't use `main_1` in your `main_page()` so you can delete this argument. So your function will looks like:

`def main_page(self):`

3. Using recursion for user input is a very bad idea. Instead of:

```
        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            main_page()
```

I recommend you to write:

```
        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            choice = input()
```

And it fixes your problem too. You are trying to call `main_page()` as:

`main_page()`

But class methods inside another class methods are called like this:

`self.main_page()`

So the final code is:

```
class Main:
    def main_page(self):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3'];
        choice = input()

        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            choice = input()

        if choice == '1':
            print("Hello world")
        elif choice == '2':
            print("back world")
        else:
            quit()

mainout = Main()
mainout.main_page()
```

Comment: Yup! I think this touches on all 4 points I outlined in my answer too.

Comment: You may not want to name a class `Main` though.

Comment: Thank you for providing a brief explanation , This solved my concern :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think you are intending to make a recursive function
2. I think you mean `self` where you have `main_1` since you do not use the argument
3. You need an `input()` instead of `print()` in your loop
4. You need to reassign `choice` *inside* your loop

Overall it would look like:

```
class Main:

    def main_page(self):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3']
        choice = input(">>>") # clear prompt

        while choice not in allchoice:
            choice = input("Invalid Please try again\n>>>") # another input with clear prompt

        if choice == '1':
            print("Hello world")
        elif choice == '2':
            print("back world")
        else:
            quit()

mainout = Main()
mainout.main_page()
```

With sample output of:

```
===== | MAIN MENU |=====
||                    ||
========================
1 - STUDENT 
2 - SUBJECT 
3 - QUIT 
>>>5
Invalid Please try again
>>>6
Invalid Please try again
>>>1
Hello world

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you for providing me an alternative way.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to pass the self to your method in order to use it after the instantiation of the class and by the way access to it through the self when calling it.

```
class Main:

    def main_page(self):
        print("===== | MAIN MENU |=====")
        print("||                    ||")
        print("========================")
        print("1 - STUDENT ")
        print("2 - SUBJECT ")
        print("3 - QUIT ")
        allchoice = ['1', '2', '3'];
        choice = input()

        while choice not in allchoice:
            print("Invalid Please try again")
            self.main_page()



        if choice == '1':
            print("Hello world")
        elif choice == '2':
            print("back world")


        else:
            quit()

mainout = Main()
mainout.main_page()
```

Comment: and please never call your class Main ... this destroys the pythonic programming paradigm

Comment: This gets me trapped. If I put `5` the first time, no matter how many times I put `1` it will continue to print the menu. I definitely don't think OP means this to be a recursive function, since if I put `1` correctly the first time the program terminates immediately. There is no way to break the loop in your code once entered

Comment: Hello thank you so much for helping me I have tried this code,yes it did trap me  to an infinite loop